# Docker in docker from a Rake task, very very slow

Tags: ruby, docker, rake, rake-task, docker-in-docker

I was wondering if some of you have tried running docker commands from a rake task itself living in a container (Docker in Docker).
I have a docker-compose network with my ruby app and a debian container which I use to do snmptranslates against.
I have a rake task that does a:

```rb
translation = `DOCKER_HOST=#{ENV['DOCKER_HOST']} docker-compose exec -T debian snmptranslate -m DAHUA-SNMP-MIB -Ot #{oid}`
```

While it works it is extremely slow (4-5 seconds for each OID...) thus making it unusable.
I might just add the `snmp` package to my base ruby (also debian) image and see if it's any better.
I've started the docker daemon with an `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file telling it to listen on any IP (0.0.0.0) without TLS and forwarded the sockets and `docker docker-compose` binaries to the container.
Has anyone experienced slow requests with Docker in Docker as well?

Comment: Are you actually running Docker-in-Docker (a separate Docker daemon in a container), or using the host's Docker socket?  Can you install `snmptranslate` in the same image, or use a [native Ruby SNMP client](https://rubygems.org/search?query=snmp), so you don't need this (extremely dangerous) invocation?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze,
In my case then no, it's not a full-on D-in-D, I'm using the host's socket yes. Started the host via `sudo dockerd` and set it to listen on `0.0.0.0` in the daemon.json file.
Invoking `snmptranslate` in my base image via Rake is extremely quick, will be using this for now.
Invoking docker from a container via the host's socket means you become root on the host??

Comment: Sure, if you can reach the Docker socket at all then you can `docker run -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/shadow` or what not and the whole host is yours.  (In your source code, what happens if `oid = '; docker run ...'`?)